# Characterizing a Parse.relation with an attribute

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm making a system where a user can tag other users with a string (previously undefined, it can be anything).

1. If I use Parse.relation where the relation is the tag string itself, users who don't use that tag will have an empty relation table created anyway, seems like a waste.
2. If I use Parse.relation named "friend", how can I further characterize it with the tag?
3. As well it should allow for multiple tags between any 2 users.

I'll be pondering more about it, any ideas for the appropriate data model given Parse's architecture are welcome!

Thanks,
Gon

Comment: Trying a model where the tag is set on the user object, and where the relation is set on the tag. In that fashion each user creates its own tags and where the tags themselves hold the relation to other users. Problem I'm facing now is that .relation doesn't seem to work on object classes other than the Parse.User class – or am I doing something wrong? 
`tagFriend: function(user) {
      var relation = this.tag.relation("friend");
      relation.add(user);
      tag.save();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the .relation on the tag, not the user. That way the tag stays a user-defined string, while its relations point to other User objects.